# custom checkout_submit_all_after observer not working

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout, ce-1.8.1.0

I am trying to write observer.for reference i am following below tutorial
http://franklinstrube.com/blog/magento-event-observers/ . but my custom observer i not getting triggered. I am using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 CE

my **app/code/local/sv/ConnectInfusion/etc/config.xml** file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <sv_ConnectInfusion>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </sv_ConnectInfusion>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ConnectInfusion>
                <class>sv_ConnectInfusion_Model</class>
            </ConnectInfusion>
        </models>
        <events>
                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <awesome_example>
                            <class>sv_ConnectInfusion_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>SyncWithInfusion</method>
                        </awesome_example>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
            </events>
        </global>
</config>
```

My Observer file is

**app/code/local/sv/ConnectInfusion/Model/Observer.php**

```
class sv_ConnectInfusion_Model_Observer {
    /**
     * This function is triggered by a Magento observer declared
     * in etc/config.xml
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function SyncWithInfusion($observer)
    {
        // Your magic code goes here...
        $event = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();

        Mage::log('Event Fired: ' . $event);
        Mage::log('yeah i am in observer !! it works' , null , 'mylog.log');
        die();
    }
}
```

and my **app/etc/modules/sv_ConnectInfusion.xml** file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <sv_ConnectInfusion>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
                <Mage_Sales/>
                <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
            </depends>
        </sv_ConnectInfusion>
    </modules>
</config>
```

what i am doing wrong? I tried by changing the xml files, adding `<depends>` , i also tried to move the code in community directory but still no luck.

Comment: `checkout_submit_all_after` only appeared in Magento 1.4. What version are you running?

Comment: i am using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 CE

Comment: Then find a event you want to use and use this, no event, no dispatching :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the moduleNamespace sv to Sv and change sv folder name to Sv

Also change model name to all lower-letter

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sv_ConnectInfusion>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Sv_ConnectInfusion>
    </modules>
<global>
    <models>
                <connectinfusion>
                    <class>Sv_ConnectInfusion_Model</class>
                </connectinfusion>
            </models>


        <events>

                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <awesome_example>
                            <class>Sv_ConnectInfusion_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>SyncWithInfusion</method>
                        </awesome_example>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
            </events>
</global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4):

`checkout_submit_all_after` is replicated for Magento CE 1.8x and you can use  `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` event in Magento CE 1.8x

Comment: You sir have just saved my keyboard from a trip out of the window!