# Event to use to fetch Order Id and not Increment Id

Tags: orders, event-observer, magento-1, increment-id

I am using the event `<sales_order_place_after>` in my observer to perform some action. I am inserting the Order ID in my custom table. But what I observe is that it does not give me Order ID but instead `Increment ID`, which I am fetching using `getReservedOrderId()`.

Now to fetch Order ID from Increment ID I can use,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($incrementId, 'increment_id');
```

but I need to insert the data at the time of order placed, instead of fetching it again.

Observer Code;

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); //returns null
```

So I am using

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getQuote();
```

Which event should be used in order to get all order details after an order is placed or on order success ?

Answer (score 3):

There are lot of event in magento order place.

I have preferred `checkout_submit_all_after event which is give Order  and Quote in there` Observer.

This event is occur  for both frontend and backend.

Example:

```
<global>
        <events>

                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <awesome_example>
                            <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                            <method>SyncWithInfusion</method>
                        </awesome_example>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
            </events>
</global>
```

and Observer code is

```
public function SyncWithInfusion(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    //get order
    $order->getId();
        $Quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();


    }
```

See at:[custom checkout_submit_all_after observer not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/custom-checkout-submit-all-after-observer-not-working)

Comment: When `checkout_submit_all_after` will be called  and how about using `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` ? I want the event that is called only when order is placed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Increment Id from the order observer use:

```
$increment_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

To get the order id use:

```
$order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned the event to be used here ?

Comment: Same as you were referring to <sales_order_place_after>

Answer (score 0):

As you figured, you cannot get the ID before the order is saved. `sales_order_place_after` is dispatched before the order actually gets saved to the database (right before the transaction is committed). The very first event that is triggered after the transaction is submitted is `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of magento 2.*

create a events.xml for

> 1.sales_order_save_after
>
> 2.sales_order_save_before

1. events.xml
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="{event_name}">
       <observer name="{class name}" instance="{namespace of class}" />
   </event>
   </config>`
2. observer code

   use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Orderpush implements ObserverInterface
{

```
protected $_class_scope_config;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->_class_scope_config = $scopeConfig;
    // parent::__construct();

}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
```

$order = $observer->getOrder(); 
     $order->getId();

}
}